# Error "No module named 'catkin_pkg'" while creating catkin_package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am creating catkin package and for that I have been following this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). I can run all the commands in that page correctly with out error except the following one

```
$ catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so
```

While I run the above command I get the error as follows

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so
Base path: /home/simbot/baxter_ws
Source space: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/src
Build space: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/build
Devel space: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/devel
Install space: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/simbot/baxter_ws/src -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/simbot/baxter_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/simbot/baxter_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/simbot/baxter_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.5.2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/simbot/baxter_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
"/home/simbot/baxter_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:167 (_catkin_package_xml)
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/simbot/baxter_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/simbot/baxter_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

From the error I can understand that I am missing `'catkin_pkg'` . So I tried to follow the instructions given in this [page](https://answers.ros.org/question/126471/cmake-failed-catkin_pkg/) by running the command `pip install catkin_pkg` and I am prompted with successful installation with the following message,

```
Collecting catkin_pkg
Collecting python-dateutil (from catkin_pkg)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils (from catkin_pkg)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/dc/bf2b15d1fa15a6f7a9e77a61b74ecbbae7258558fcda8ffc9a6638a6b327/docutils-0.15.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from catkin_pkg)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/fa/0160cd525c62d7abd076a070ff02b2b94de589f1a9789774f17d7c54058e/pyparsing-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil->catkin_pkg)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, docutils, pyparsing, catkin-pkg
Successfully installed catkin-pkg-0.4.14 docutils-0.15.2 pyparsing-2.4.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0 six-1.12.0
```

After that I perform `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then running the first command I still get the missing `catkin_pkg` error. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336264/error-%22no-module-named-%27catkin_pkg%27%22-while-creating-catkin_package/) by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why you try to use python 3 use python2 as kinetic use only phython2.

Are you a arch Linux user? Because then you have to enter the error throwing line.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-10-28**:
I am not an Arch Linux user. But I still want to use Pythin3 based catkin_make for my future developments.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-10-28**:
Then you may have to uninstall python2 or use pip3 to install the proper libraries

Melodic use python2 as default.

On arch Linux you have only python3

The answer here may help you https://answers.ros.org/question/295012/how-can-i-install-ros-melodic-with-python3/

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-10-28**:
Thank you for pointing to the right post and that answers my question.